# Free Pascal without Lazarus

Tags: command-line, freepascal

Could any of you chaps point me in the direction of a good tutorial or book for Free Pascal that does not rely on using Lazarus?  Ideally I would like just to write code in a text editor and compile/link using the command-line.  I have no existing knowledge of Pascal at all.

Unfortunately all the material I have uncovered through Google assumes the use of Lazarus, prior knowledge of Pascal or refers only to the pre-Delphi/FPC versions of Pascal without 'modern' features such as dynamic strings, objects and so forth.

Answer (score 3):

Lazarus doesn't change the base dialect possibilities. It is only an IDE and visual library over freepascal, nearly everything nonvisual is FPC.

Just install FPC and compile with

```
 fpc <programname>
```

As reference for the dialect see the Free Pascal reference guide, which contains nonvisual examples. When you have a base level of knowledge, you can adapt Lazarus related examples to your own environment.

Comment: Will that teach me real basics like how to write an entry point, subroutines and control structures?

Comment: They are tersely described of course in the ref manual, but it isn't a tutorial. Most use Delphi and TP resources for that.

Comment: You can try turbo pascal tutorials, almost everything works. Only things that are too 16bit/dos specific wont work.